# How to apply Gauss' Law given charge?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electricity, charge, gauss-law

[image]

How I approached this question is by adding the two charges and dividing by epsilon zero. (Gauss' Law)
 Is this the correct way to solve this problem?

Comment: You did answer your question. You add the charges inside the pyramid.

Answer (score 0):

Gauss' law states that the *net* flux of the electric field $\vec E$ through a surface is simply related to the *net* charge enclosed by that surface:
$$
\oint \vec E\cdot d\vec S= \frac{q_{net}}{\epsilon_0}
$$
Thus only the net charge matters.

In relation to your specific example, Gauss' law does not states that the flux need be the same through 
all $4$ sides of your pyramid - the flux through *individual* surfaces depends on the location of the charges - but is a statement about the *total flux* through the $4$ sides.

To see this net flux does not depend on the location of the charges, imagine an analogy with a 60W lightbulb surrounded by a cubical lampshade.  If you move the lightbulb around, the *total*  amount of light through the lampshade will not change - that's determined by the 60W lightbulb only.  Of course if you move the lightbulb close to one side, more light will escape through *that* side but less light would escape through the *other* side, without changing the *total* amount of light through all sides.  If you want more light through your shade, you need to increase the 60W to a 120W bulb, which is the equivalent of increasing the charge enclosed in your Gaussian surface.